# how to make DRF not return the 401 error if token is invalid?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I use REST Framework's TokenAuthentication and a client in the authorization header may attach

a wrong token (like "Token null") and

a right token (like "Token zfuhhluwezfhzwiefuzweufm").

In the first case, REST Framework returns the 401 error even if a view allows any request.
My question is how to make DRF not return the 401 error if a token is not valid and let view handle the request?

Answer (score 0):

you Need to Create your custom View ... Not the ready token view in the framework I think ..